# Suppressing text with strikethrough?

Tags: environments, soul

I would like to suppress text that has been strickenthrough (struckthrough?). I don't think that `hide` does this, because `hide` replaces with an empty box of the same size.

I think something like `\renewcommand\st` that replaces whatever each instance of `\st{ }\` with nothing would work well, but I cannot figure out how to do this (nor I have a found another post that quite does this).

Minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\begin{document}

This text should remain visible 
\st{but the strikethrough text should just disappear} 
so that thus just flows from the word visible before the strikethrough.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps `\renewcommand\st[1]{\unskip}`, after loading the `soul` package.  The `\unskip` prevents the fore and aft spaces from showing up as two separate space tokens.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You mean that you would like a command that makes its argument to be simply ignored?

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you.

Comment: @Vincent that is precisely it. The suggestions above annuls the command and then removes and extra space issues.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes perhaps better would be `\renewcommand\st[1]{\ifhmode\unskip\fi}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to use `\unskip` like suggested by [@StevenB.Segletes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/527974/suppressing-text-with-strikethrough#comment1335188_527974). But instead I'd prefer to use `\@bsphack\@esphack`, as `\unskip` would gobble a space before `\st`, even if there is no space following it (the following illustrates this).

Additionally I'd use `\ifhmode` for the `\unskip` solution, as you'd typically not want to remove any vertical space, and the `\@bpshack\@esphack` solution doesn't need it, as `\@bsphack` and `\@esphack` both test `\ifhmode` themselves.

### What I'd use:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{soul}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\st[1]{\@bsphack\@esphack}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
This text should remain visible.
\st{but the strikethrough text should just disappear} 
So that thus just flows from the word visible before the strikethrough.
\end{document}
```

### Example comparing both solutions:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{soul}

\begin{document}
This text should remain visible.
\st{but the strikethrough text should just disappear} 
So that thus just flows from the word visible before the strikethrough.

\renewcommand\st[1]{\ifhmode\unskip\fi}%
This text should remain visible.
\st{but the strikethrough text should just disappear} 
So that thus just flows from the word visible before the strikethrough.

\noindent
\makebox[\linewidth][s]
  {%
    This text should remain visible.
    \st{but the strikethrough text should just disappear}%
    So that thus%
  }

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\st[1]{\@bsphack\@esphack}%
\makeatother
\noindent
\makebox[\linewidth][s]
  {%
    This text should remain visible.
    \st{but the strikethrough text should just disappear}%
    So that thus%
  }

This text should remain visible.
\st{but the strikethrough text should just disappear} 
So that thus just flows from the word visible before the strikethrough.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In the example, this solution works great. When I put it into my working document, though, it prints the phrase "bsphackesphack" everywhere where I've used `\st`. Do `\@bsphack` and `\@esphack` collide with other packages? (Incidentally, I experimented with placing the `renewcommand` line at different places, including after the last package call).

Comment: @CSev you need to use `\makeatletter` before and `\makeatother` after the `\renewcommand`, otherwise you can't access macros that have a `@` in their name and try to use `\@` instead (in this case), which does something completely different. As you might know, TeX only allows for letters in control sequence names, `\makeatletter` changes the category of `@` to be considered a letter.